# How much ammo will a Medic see on their HUD while healing a spy?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy, tf2-medic

In a relatively recent update, Medics gained the ability to see how much ammo their heal target has for their currently selected weapon. This got me thinking about a medic healing/ubering a spy, because presumably they'll never display anything but full ammo.  Or possibly even determining the identity of a spy because of their never-changing ammo count.

How much ammo does a medic's HUD display when healing an enemy spy disguised as a teammnate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some testing using bots, I have concluded that:

- Disguised Spies show a random amount of loaded ammo to enemy Medics. It appears to be uniformly random, with some example numbers for Pyros and Heavies (/200) being 16, 54, 71, 97, 107, 129, 134, and 147. As a result, you'll appear to have full ammo only `1/clip` of the time (0 doesn't seem valid outside melee weapons etc), so unless your held weapon doesn't need to reload the Medic will probably not want to über you.

  - I can't test this on my own, but this *might* mean that you can see an ammo number for the Cow Mangler, Righteous Bison, or Pomson that isn't a multiple of 5. Since the Medic ammo display shows these weapons' loaded ammo as multiples of 5 (as I remember), this will be a dead giveaway.
- Reloading your Revolver does not change the number. Usually a fake-reload will help your disguise, but if an observant Medic's healing you, this will blow it.
- Changing disguise weapon re-randomizes the number. This one's very hard to notice.
- I can't test on my own whether collecting ammo pickups affects the number, but I suspect not.
- Since it's random, the Spy has no idea what he's displaying.
- Just like real Medics and Spies, Medic and Spy disguises show "ÜberCharge: 0%" or "Disguised as X" instead of an ammo count.

Comment: I would very much like to know if collecting ammo changes your randomized ammo count, since if it does, that would be a huge game changer for whether or not you want to pick up ammo while an unknowing Medic is healing you.

Comment: @Zibbobz - If your cloak is full and revolver ammo is full, you won't ever pick up ammo boxes, so I would hazard that its no :)